# Pass !, !=, ~, <, > as parameters

Tags: python, arguments, parameters, args, keyword-argument

I want to be able to pass arguments like this:

```
fn(a>=b) or fn(a!=b)
```

I saw this behavior in DjangoORM and SQLAlchemy but I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: It's not quite what you're asking for, but in the general case you can pass e.g. `operator.ne` (for `!=`) and `operator.gt` (for `>`) around

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ORMs use [*special methods*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames) on classes for `a` and `b` to hook into operators and customise what is produced.

`>=` for is handled by the [`object.__ge__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ge__), while `!=` calls [`object.__ne__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__).

Typically, the ORM object used for `a` returns a new object with the operation applied, allowing you to chain operations, and the `fn()` function expects such an ORM object and will read the operation status from there.